# java.lang.NullPointerException when parsinng date

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate

I am getting exception when sending request from my rest client
        This is my DTO class

```
        private String fromDate;
        private String toDate;

        public String getFromDate() {
            return fromDate;
        }
        public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
            this.fromDate = fromDate;
        }
        public String getToDate() {
            return toDate;
        }
        public void setToDate(String toDate) {
            this.toDate = toDate;
        }
```

request packet is this format how to send date in this format but it will take as String

```
{
" toDate": "2014/07/01",
  " fromDate ": "2014/05/01",
  " imeiNo ": "1234567890",
  " phoneNumber ": 1234567890,
  " emailId ": ""
}
```

here is my method for converting in helper class

```
private static Timestamp convertStringDateToTimestamp(String stringDate)
    {

        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date = null;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
        try {
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(stringDate);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

        return timeStamp;
    }
```

but getting this exception in my server

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.omnypay.mobileapp.webservices.helper.TransactionHelper.convertStringDateToTimestamp(Tra
```

Please help me

Comment: Unless you point out the line the code, it's all done to guess work, however, this ... `java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime())` ... is potential problem.  If the `String` failed to be parsed for some reason, then `date` will still be `null`

Comment: You're probably getting a `ParseException` first, which you're effectively ignoring. **Don't do that.** If you get a `ParseException`, you clearly can't continue, so why are you just printing the stack trace and ignoring it?

Comment: The format you are using, `yy-MM-dd` and the format of the date `String`s are wrong `2014/07/01`, the format should be more like `yyyy/MM/dd`, this will cause a `ParseException` and `date` will be `null`.  You need to add debug statements into your code...

Comment: Date date = null; in case of this what i have to take as i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

If the formatter does not parse the string as a date, the `date` variable is `null` and you cannot call `date.getTime()`.

Add a null check before that line.

OR

As Jon says, you need to handle the Exception better. Either throw the exception once you have printed the stacktrace, or return a value so that the program execution does not continue to the rest of the method.

Comment: @JonSkeet assuming that he wants to break there ofcourse.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "break" in this case, but either letting the exception bubble up, or returning the appropriate value in the `catch` block would avoid this problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess. I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your date have `/` as separator but you are defining `-` as a separator in your formatter. And also you have full year like 2014 not 14 Change it to

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```